# How to get the information of a specific object that is retrived from a django model using for loop

Tags: django

I have a boostrap slider which is populating using for loop and django model objects now I want that if I click on any of the slider object then it show me the information related to that specific object which I clicked the Information must be retrived from the **django model.**
**Thanks** In Advance please help me to get out of this situation ..

**Here is my code which is populating the slider. I want when I clicked on any object in the loop it should only show me the information related to that object or How can I access and display the name and description of individual product diplayed using for loop in django**

```
 {% for product in products %}
<div class="services-block-two">
<div class="inner-box">
<div class="image">
<a href="building-construction.html"><img src="/{{ product.prd_logo }}" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div class="lower-content">
<h3><a href="building-construction.html">{{ product.prd_name }}</a></h3>
<div class="text">{{ product.prd_des }}</div>
<a href="building-construction.html" class="read-more">Read More <span class="arrow flaticon-next"></span></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

[here is a image of product i want to display the name,logo and description of the product on different web page when user would click on that product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8TcG.jpg)

Comment: show information where and how. same web page or what ?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I want to show the clicked product information(name,description,image) on different web page which is linked with Read More option in my code..